# Cannot edit content of new or existing CMS Pages

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have just discovered that since a short while, I cannot figure out if it's a few days or a few weeks, we are unable to edit the content of new or existing CMS pages.

I can edit the title, but not the content itself. The WYSIWYG editor buttons are not showing. When editing a static block, everything works fine.

See here what happens:
http://postimg.org/image/v1ib7wbcn/

System.log doesn't show anything strange. Exception.log is showing:

```
2016-01-11T11:20:09+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid blocktype: Mage_Mpblog_Block_Rss_Wrapper' in /home/scrobby/domains/scrobby.nl/public_html/app/Mage.php:594

Stack trace:
0 /home/scrobby/domains/scrobby.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid blocktype...')
1 /home/scrobby/domains/scrobby.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('mpblog/rss_wrap...', Array)
2 /home/scrobby/domains/scrobby.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('mpblog/rss_wrap...', 'mpblog.rss.wrap...')
3 /home/scrobby/domains/scrobby.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('mpblog/rss_wrap...', 'mpblog.rss.wrap...')
4 /home/scrobby/domains/scrobby.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
5 /home/scrobby/domains/scrobby.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
6 /home/scrobby/domains/scrobby.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
7 /home/scrobby/domains/scrobby.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
8 /home/scrobby/domains/scrobby.nl/public_html/app/code/community/Magpleasure/Guestbook/controllers/IndexController.php(53): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
9 /home/scrobby/domains/scrobby.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Magpleasure_Guestbook_IndexController->indexAction()
10 /home/scrobby/domains/scrobby.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
11 /home/scrobby/domains/scrobby.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
12 /home/scrobby/domains/scrobby.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
13 /home/scrobby/domains/scrobby.nl/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
14 /home/scrobby/domains/scrobby.nl/public_html/index.php(96): Mage::run('default', 'store')
15 {main}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Follow this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510318/magento-wysiwyg-editor-button-not-working

Comment: Hi Manish, thanks for the tip, unfortunately that didn't work. TinyMCE is working with static blocks, it's just not showing the buttons and the content when editing CMS pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found the solution. The test environment had the same issue, but some different information in the system.log

```
2016-01-14T09:35:38+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/cms/page/edit/form/renderer/content.phtml
```

For some reason some files were not present in the adminhtml/base/default and/or adminhtml/default/default folders. I copied them back from the original installation files, problem solved!